# Why do we need to set keywindow in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

> Whereas touch events are delivered to the window where they occurred,
>   events that do not have a relevant coordinate value are delivered to
>   the key window. Only one window at a time can be the key window, and
>   you can use a window’s  isKeyWindow property to determine its status.
>   Most of the time, your app’s main window is the key window, but UIKit
>   may designate a different window as needed.
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

  // Initialize the window
  window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

  // Set Background Color of window
  window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

  // Allocate memory for an instance of the 'MainViewController' class
  let mainViewController = MainViewController()

  // Set the root view controller of the app's window
  window!.rootViewController = mainViewController

  // Make the window visible
  window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

  return true
}
```

I read that but still did not understand why do we need to set a window to key window.

> Whereas touch events are delivered to the window where they occurred,
>   events that do not have a relevant coordinate value are delivered to
>   the key window

What is the effect of making a window a key, it not then what happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- The `makeKeyAndVisible` message makes a window key, and moves it to be
  in front of any other windows on its level.
- The call to `makeKeyAndVisible` is used to specify which one is current.
- It assigns the new view controller to the window’s rootViewController property and then makes the window visible on the screen.

  *- This is a convenience method to show the current window and position it in front of all other windows at the same level or lower. If you only want to show the window, change its 
  hidden
  property to 
  NO*
  .
  [see Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621601-makekeyandvisible?preferredLanguage=occ)